# Is this poission Distribution problem?

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

In a retirement village the average length of stay is 15.6 years. what is the probability that someone lived 8.8 years will vacate soon?

thanks

Comment: Sounds like survival analysis?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 2):

I presume that "Is this poission Distribution problem?" means "Should I use the Poission distribution to solve this problem?". I would say no. The Poisson distribution models events that can happen any number of times, at a given rate. And it produces a count of events over a given period of time. Your problem concerns an event that can happen only once, and you want to know the waiting time till the event.